# How can I set a new Lat and Lng on click with Leaflet?

Tags: angular, dictionary, leaflet

I'm trying to update the Leaflet coordinates when I click on a new place. I already created a method that capture all information of this selected place, but I don't know how I upgrade it to the map.

The model class

```
export class Maps{
    id: number;
    address: {
        coordinates: {
            coordinates: {
                0: number,
                1: number
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

The map-component.ts

```
export class MapsListComponent implements OnInit {

  maps: Maps[] = [];
  selectedMap: Maps;
  selectedLat;
  selectedLng;
```

Where I get all the maps

```
getMaps(){
    this.userService.maps().subscribe(
      resMaps => {
        this.maps = resMaps.maps;
      });
   }
```

The selected map

```
 onSelectMap(maps: Maps): void{
    this.selectedMap = maps;
    this.selectedLat = maps.address.coordinates.coordinates[0];
    this.selectedLng =  maps.address.coordinates.coordinates[1];  

    console.log(this.selectedMap)
    console.log(this.selectedLat)
    console.log(this.selectedLng)
  }
```

And I get all the new coordinates on console, everyone of them.

But can't set to the Leaflet LatLng options

```
options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
      })
    ],
    zoom:15,
    //I tried this but failed
    center: latLng(this.selectedLat, this.selectedLng)
  };
```

Do you guys have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, just changed the onSelectMap and added one line.

```
 onSelectMap(maps: Maps){
    this.selectedMap = maps;
    this.selectedLat = maps.address.coordinates.coordinates[0];
    this.selectedLng =  maps.address.coordinates.coordinates[1];  

    **this.map.panTo(new L.LatLng(this.selectedLat, this.selectedLng));**

    console.log(this.selectedMap)
    console.log(this.selectedLat)
    console.log(this.selectedLng)
  }
```

Added this method too

```
onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
  this.map = map;
}
```

And the html file

```
 <div id="map" leaflet [leafletOptions]="options" (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"></div>
```